# Memory Interpretation Graph - Munin

Tags: memory, munin

Yesterday I rebooted the web server machine, but I'm trying to figure out why the graph below shows prior rebooting the memory almost full of cache and just a bit of active memory used. Would there be any problem keeping it the same was it was or rebooting every ~30 days is what I'm suppose to do?

Thanks

http://img513.imageshack.us/i/localhostlocaldomainmem.png/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](http://egloo.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/linux-cached-memory/), it might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: nice answer! short, to the point, and exactly what the OP needed.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Linux likes to use all otherwise-unused memory for disk cache.  There's no performance downside, and there just might be a benefit because the disk won't need to be touched for some disk reads.

Comment: Exactly.  Using memory for cache is GOOD.  Enjoy it.  And whatever you do, don't reboot a Unix server every 30 days.  They're meant to run for a LONG time.

Comment: I think Lee B means "don't reboot a Unix server unless you have a good reason."  Security updates which involve kernel updates, are a Good Reason.  If someone shows you an uptime of more than 90 days, odds are very good you can show them a machine that has unpatched kernel vulnerabilities.